# Why was my question about software awards closed?

Tags: discussion

This question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/252095/who-gives-out-the-awards-to-award-winning-software

Is about the software development industry and is very relevant to programming.  Why was it put on hold?

Comment: Being relevant to programming isn't the only requirement for questions on Programmers. Have you read our [What topics can I ask about here?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) article? In which of the broad topics presented there do you think your question belongs?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the FAQ clearly articulates why this question would be off-topic.

Comment: as far as I can see, question is not unique to programming (fails the ["topicality diagram"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/P6bIb.png) test). "Who gives out awards to..." restaurants, who gives out awards to scientists, to bakers, clip-makers, strip dancers, freedom fighters etc etc etc

Comment: related: [What's with all the “close” votes?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261824/839601)

Comment: @CaptainCodeman - calling people names isn't helpful. And we do expect people to have at least skimmed the "What topics can I ask about here?" page.

Comment: @gnat The question is unique to programming, because if there is a body giving awards to software, it does not relate to bakers, strippers, and pornstars as you mentioned.

Comment: @ChrisF Calling people names can be helpful if it helps illustrate the mistakes of their behavior.  In this case, the person was trying to make himself feel superior by giving a flippant answer to a legitimate question.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman This isn't an opinion. In no unclear terms, rudeness is not tolerated here.

Comment: @maple_shaft Well then you should speak to the people who are being rude to me.

Answer (score 2):

This really has nothing to do with software development specifically and is pretty widely known as a general marketing gimmick for any number and types of products and services.  We have to draw the line somewhere on questions that really transcend the area of programming and  require expertise in other areas not related to software development.

For more information and some light hearted humour here is a link to the [original "boat programming" question](http://web.archive.org/web/20100426125115/http://www.mattmcdole.com/boat/) that spawned the famous meme.

It is not that we can't answer this for you or that a member of the community doesn't know the answer, it is that the knowledge for this lies outside of software development as a whole. We do encourage however that you visit our chat room for such questions that don't really fit our site.

Comment: It does have to do with software development specifically.  If there was a body giving awards to software, it would NOT be applicable to other products and services.